# Autoscaling instance groups used for HTCondor batch workloads?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've set up an HTCondor cluster using google cloud, following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/analyzing-portfolio-risk-using-htcondor-and-compute-engine).

I like it other than the autoscaling feature. I want something simpler than a target cpu utilization average across all instances in the group. I'd like to just delete a machine if HTCondor has no use for it, once there are not enough jobs to use all of the available clusters.

I could try using instances that delete themselves after a certain amount of time without any use. But then the autoscaler would just spin up another machine. I'd need to change automatically delete the machine and lower the maximum number of replicas.

Any ideas for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial you linked sets instance group to have 2 instance at all times. I assume you already adjusted that.
You can edit autoscaling behavior of your HTCondor instance group by entering **Compute Engine** → **Instance groups** → *HTCondor group name* → **Edit group** and pressing pencil under **Autoscaling policy**

Example metric:
[image: autoscaling]

More information about autoscaling an instance group can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/autoscaling-instance-group-with-custom-stackdrivers-metric).

Comment: This is a great response and looks like it would work well, thank you!

I've discovered another approach more specific to HTCondor that also works well. The `condor_status` command lists the name of each instance. I can simply identify instances that have had the status "Idle" for longer than some set period of time, and then delete them using `gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances` to remove them. A simple way to automatically scale down, after manually scaling up.